# Идентификация треугольника на FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Есть такой код :

```
format  PE GUI 4.0
 include 'WIN32AX.INC'
.data
formats db "%d",0
result db 256 dup(?) ; Когда будем преобразовывать число в строку, сюда сохраним результат
A  db   02h   ; стороны
B  db   02h   ; треугольника
C  db   04h   ;

.code  
start:

   MOV  DL,byte[C]  
   MOV  AL,byte[A]  
   MOV  BL,byte[B]

   CMP  AL,BL            ;  сравнение  
   JNE  NOT_EQABC  
   CMP  BL,DL  
   JNE  NOT_EQABC

invoke MessageBox,0,result,"треугольник равносторонний",MB_OK ;Выводим результат на экран.  
  JMP  METKA       ; переход  на метку

 NOT_EQABC: CMP     AL,BL  
     JE EQUAL  
     CMP        BL,DL  
      JE        EQUAL  
      CMP       AL,DL  
      JE   EQUAL  
;  
invoke MessageBox,0,result,"треугольник обычный",MB_OK ;Выводим результат на экран.  
     JMP        METKA  
     EQUAL:  
;
invoke MessageBox,0,result,"треугольник равнобедренный ",MB_OK ;Выводим результат на экран.

METKA:    invoke ExitProcess,0          ;Выход из программы  
    .end start
```

Это программа идентификации треугольника. Мне нужно добавить ещё два блока проверки : 
проверить, может  ли существовать треугольник, проверить, является ли треугольник прямоугольным.

Блоки должны быть примерно такими же

```
 CMP  AL,BL            ;  сравнение  
   JNE  NOT_EQABC  
   CMP  BL,DL  
   JNE  NOT_EQABC

invoke MessageBox,0,result,"треугольник равносторонний",MB_OK ;Выводим результат на экран.
```

Это fasm32 ассемблер...  Кто знает, как это сделать, подскажите.

Comment: @cyber922, а по какому принципу собираетесь проверять, может ли треугольник существовать? А, туплю, сумма двух меньших сторон должна быть меньше или равна большей стороне.

Comment: Про прямоугольность могу сказать, что нужно найти наибольшую строну и проверить, чтобы ее квадрат равнялся сумме квадратов двух других сторон (теорема Пифагора же).

Comment: это я знаю, как в коде реализовать, вот в чем проблема :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно найти наибольшую сторону:

```
mov al,[A]
mov bl,[B]
mov cl,[C]
cmp al,bl
jae @f ; если al>=bl (без учета знака), то переход вперед (f - от слова forward) до ближайшей метки @@ 
xchg al,bl
@@:
cmp al,cl
jae @f
xchg al,cl
@@: ; Теперь у нас в al лежит наибольшая сторона, в bl и cl две меньшие
```

Чтобы треугольник существовал, нужно чтобы значения bl+cl были не меньше al. Сумму поместим например в dl, чтобы значения можно было использовать еще раз:

```
mov dl,bl
add dl,cl
cmp al,dl
ja не_существует ; выводим что треугольник не существует и выходим
; существует
```

Теперь можно проверить треугольник на прямоугольность. Нужно значение в al умножить само на себя, куда-то сохранить (в dx например), потом в al положить значение из bl, тоже умножить само на себя, положить в bx, потом в al положить значение из cl, умножить само на себя и прибавить к bx. Дальше сравниваем bx и dx, если равны - значит треугольник прямоугольный.

```
; в al лежит значение наибольшей стороны (если треугольник прямоугольный - то это гипотенуза)
mul al ; умножаем al само на себя, результат в ax
mov dx,ax ; сохраняем ax в dx для последующего сравнения
mov al,bl
mul al
mov bx,ax ; сохраняем квадрат одной из меньших сторон в bx
mov al,cl
mul al
add bx,ax ; суммируем квадраты меньших сторон, результат в bx
cmp dx,bx ; сравниваем квадрат большей стороны и сумму квадратов меньших сторон
je прямоугольный ; если равны, то треугольник прямоугольный
; не прямоугольный
```

Кстати, result не нужен, потому что в данной задаче ответ не формируется через wsprintf, а просто пишется прямым текстом:

```
invoke MessageBox, 0, "Текст сообщения (например что треугольник равносторонний)", "Заголовок", MB_OK
```

Comment: В проверке существования напутал с условием( Поправил.